# I can't post data to database with AJAX in Laravel 5.2

Tags: ajax, database, post, laravel-5

I am trying to send / post data to database with AJAX in laravel 5.2 but I am not able to post data to database with AJAX. what is the problem I can not figure out this.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please add code in text format, using the code formatting tool provided (it's a four space indent, in Markdown). Images are not a suitable way of showing code, mainly because it prevents people from copying the code to try it.

Comment: Have you checked to see if your AJAX operation starts? What is the response of the operation? Use the Network tab in your browser to examine this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your problem is with csrf token. So check this link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection

Read about X-CSRF-TOKEN

---

X-CSRF-TOKEN

In addition to checking for the CSRF token as a POST parameter, the Laravel VerifyCsrfToken middleware will also check for the X-CSRF-TOKEN request header. You could, for example, store the token in a "meta" tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Once you have created the meta tag, you can instruct a library like jQuery to add the token to all request headers. This provides simple, convenient CSRF protection for your AJAX based applications:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```